# C# - Change permisson registry when denied

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I have a key with the following permissions:

```
Allow SYSTEM FullControl
Allow Administrators FullControl
Allow Users FullControl
Deny Everyone FullControl
Owner: User
```

The `User` is member of the `Users group`.

How can I change the permissions of this key using C#?

I saw that in C# there's a method called `SetAccessRules()` but I can't read the key so I can't use it!

Comment: Please provide more informaition about your problem and have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not how security works.  When you get to a locked door you don't try to get in by replacing the lock.  The permissions you describe of course don't match the runtime behavior.  So high odds that you are accessing the wrong key.  Standard mishap on a 64-bit operating system when you forced your program to run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: In Windows, Owner always changes permission even when denied all access. I can change permission of the key in regedit editor but i don't know how to change in C#.

Comment: @hawk. I have a key but denied all access. How to change permission of this key by using Owner's permission. we will need taking ownership on this key

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Usually when people ask how to change permissions on registry keys they are trying to solve a problem the wrong way. Of course, you only presented the solution rather than the problem and are now suffering the curse of the XY question.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

You can't

## Long(er) Answer

If your process doesn't have rights to read the registry key, you certainly don't have enough access to change the permissions on the key. Basically, the permission levels are as follows:

- Read
- Write
- Full Control

Read will obviously allow you to read the keys, write allows you to modify the keys (and implicitly read them), full control allows you to change permissions, plus implicitly read or modify the keys.

To be able to do what you are trying to do, your process must have the full control permission for the key, or contact a system administrator who can grant you the permissions that you require on the key.

From what information you've put in your question, I'd be questioning why you are doing this. Are you taking the right course of action in trying to solve the underlying problem that you have? What is the actual underlying problem that you're trying to solve, because there is probably a better way of solving that problem than what you're trying to do here.

Comment: thanks for answer. 
because i'm bad at english so i don't describe my problem.
in web page: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530%28v=WS.10%29.aspx] talk that: **The owner can always change permissions on an object, even when denied all access to the object.**. hence if i run app on user is owner i can change permission. Morever i can run app by admin. Then i take ownership .When i had ownership permission, i could change permission. I did it with regedit.exe. Why regedit editor do it, c# do not?

Comment: @Tiniki If you have administrator rights, then yes _you_ can do this, but for your software to be able to do this, it also has to be executed with administrative rights (don't forget UAC can play a part in this), this will allow you to then take ownership and reset permissions.

Comment: so, can i do it in c# if i have administrator rights?